# Assembly Random Number Using Irvine

Tags: assembly, random, numbers, masm, irvine32

When I implement the random number generator procedure that was provided for us in Assembly, half the time it gives me a division by zero error and the other half of the time it works perfectly. I believe that I am implementing the code properly, but will provide you how I have it written.

```
randomCompNum PROC
    call Randomize               ;Sets seed
    mov  eax,10                  ;Keeps the range 0 - 9

    call RandomRange
    mov  compNum1,eax            ;First random number

L1: call RandomRange
    .IF eax == compNum1          ;Checks if the second number is the same as the first
        jmp L1                   ;If it is, repeat call
    .ENDIF
     mov compNum2,eax            ;Second random number

L2: call RandomRange
    .IF eax == compNum1          ;Checks if the third number is the same as the first
        jmp L2                   ;If it is, repeat
    .ELSEIF eax == compNum1      ;Checks if the third number is the same as the second
        jmp L2                   ;If it is, repeat
    .ENDIF
    mov compNum3,eax             ;Third random number stored

    ret

randomCompNum ENDP
```

---

Here's the disassembly for RandomRange that Visual Studios provided me

```
_RandomRange@0:
004019C1  push         ebx  
004019C2  push         edx  
004019C3  mov          ebx,eax  
004019C5  call         _Random32@0 (4019A6h)  ;<---- This function doesn't touch ebx
004019CA  mov          edx,0  
004019CF  div          eax,ebx     ;<---- That's where the error occurs
004019D1  mov          eax,edx  
004019D3  pop          edx  
004019D4  pop          ebx  
004019D5  ret
```

Do you know what could be causing this error?

I'm tempted to just create my own random number generator.

**Background on the RandomRange method:** It's simple. You set the seed with Randomize, moving 10 into eax keeps the RandomRange between 0 - 9. That's all the documentation I could find for that function, so that's all I believe there is about it.

Comment: There's no such instruction as "div eax, ebx". What's the real code?

Comment: That was the code that the disassembler gave to me. I didn't write it.

Comment: How's that instruction encoded? What are the bytes that make it up (they would've been at addresses 004019CF and 004019D0)?

Comment: That was honestly all I could find on that function, which is mainly my problem.

Comment: AFAIR, there's an option in Visual Studio's context menu to show the instruction bytes.

Comment: I've got the code bytes:
    004019CF F7 F3                div         eax,ebx  
    004019D1 8B C2                mov         eax,edx

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Assembly and VS

Comment: I can't see a problem in the presented code (or the library). Are you sure it's this place that has a division problem? Are you sure you didn't pass 0 to RandomRange in some other place in your program? Are you sure your code didn't corrupt itself or the library? Do sample programs from chapter 5 and 8 work? They use RandomRange.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but a friend of mine just referenced it.

Your `mov eax, 10` belongs to the `call RandomRange`, so your sample of code should read:

```
randomCompNum PROC
    call Randomize               ;Sets seed

    mov  eax,10                  ;Keeps the range 0 - 9
    call RandomRange
    mov  compNum1,eax            ;First random number

L1: mov  eax,10                  ;Keeps the range 0 - 9
    call RandomRange
    .IF eax == compNum1          ;Checks if the second number is the same as the first
        jmp L1                   ;If it is, repeat call
    .ENDIF
     mov compNum2,eax            ;Second random number

L2: mov  eax,10                  ;Keeps the range 0 - 9
    call RandomRange
    .IF eax == compNum1          ;Checks if the third number is the same as the first
        jmp L2                   ;If it is, repeat
    .ELSEIF eax == compNum1      ;Checks if the third number is the same as the second
        jmp L2                   ;If it is, repeat
    .ENDIF
    mov compNum3,eax             ;Third random number stored

    ret
randomCompNum ENDP
```

The `mov eax,10` is the parameter sent to the RandomRange function, it would be `RandomRange(10);` in C.
Note that because RandomRange returns its result in eax, you need to set it up before each call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random32  PROC
;
; Generates an unsigned pseudo-random 32-bit integer
;   in the range 0 - FFFFFFFFh.
```

Random32 CAN return 0 that is probably why it is bombing on you when you divide by 0 :-)

The Irvine source is available, just modify RandomRange to handle a 0 when returned from Random32

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to access the file. I've tried tracing through the included files in Irvine32.inc, but I can't find the actual code to change. Should I just copy and paste the disassembly and re-write it?

Comment: I don't think it's a valid recommendation. RandomRange returns a value that's smaller than the argument (see the help file). And both are unsigned values. So, if you pass 0 to RandomRange, what non-negative integer smaller than 0 should it return?

Answer (score 0):

[Help File for Irvine Library](http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/files/IrvineLibHelp.exe)

[Irvine32 Source Files](http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/examples/index.htm)